# Set environment variables from .list files of key/value pairs in .bachrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables

I want to set environment variables from **.list** (key/value) files

So inside my **.bachrc** file i'm calling this file :

**.bachrc:**

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

source $HOME/file.list
```

The problem is that my file.list contains vars like those  :

**file.list:**

```
myVarOne=Abc!=;;$
myVarTwo=jfv^$+-
```

So whhen running terminal : it throw syntax errors in those files ; so i was forced to not work wth .list files  , but with shell files and write vars like this (adding cotes) :

```
myVarOne="Abc!=;;$"
myVarTwo="jfv^$+-"
```

Since i want to keep using **.list** files **and not shell** format ,

how may i do it ?

**Sugesstions ?**

Comment: If you are going to use `source`, then `file.list` is subject to the same evaluation process as any other script. `myVarOne='Abc!=;;$'` and `myVarTwo='jfv^$+-'`. That is going to be far safer than trying to parse the file in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps you, instead of using `source`, you can put the following command. (Do it only if you are sure about contents of your file.list)

```
eval $(sed "s/=\(.*\)/=\"\1\"/" file.list)
```

Or you can simply do like:

```
sed "s/=\(.*\)/=\"\1\"/" file.list > tempfile ; source tempfile
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code in your bashrc

```
while read line; 
do  
    key="$( cut -d '=' -f 1 <<< $line)"
    value="$( cut -d '=' -f 2- <<< "$line" )"
    export $key=$value
done <file.list
```

Comment: `IFS= read -r key value` will avoid the need for `cut`. You still need to quote `$key=$value`, though.